# PWA funciona corretamente no navegador mas não funciona corretamente no smartphone?

Tags: https, pwa

Fiz um PWA e realizei todos os testes no navegador e tudo saiu dentro do esperado, porém quando faço o teste em meu smartphone ele não pede autorização para enviar notificações e também não pede para ser adicionado na tela inicial do smartphone.

Um dos problemas que eu tinha era a falta de um protocolo HTTPS, porém gerei um localmente e coloquei no servidor.

Mas o Chrome não reconhece ele como válido, fica o HTTPS vermelho na barra de endereços, mas o PWA abre normalmente e como falei acima, faz as ações esperadas mesmo com o HTTPS estando vermelho, e no smartphone ele não faz nenhuma das ações esperadas.

Poderia ser isso por causa do certificado gerado por mim mesmo??

Comment: porque as tags javascript, firebase e vue.js? O problema, aparentemente, não possui nenhuma relação com nada disso

Comment: São tecnologias que usei para criar o pwa, talvez alguém que também as usou passou pelo mesmo problema

Comment: Vou dar um exemplo, estou com problema nas regras de segurança do firebase (erro: "permission denied at..."), adianta colocar a tag CSS, apenas porque eu uso? Não, as tags servem para categorizar o problema e não o projeto do problema, até porque, se você fosse colocar todas as tecnologias usadas na sua aplicação, com certeza ultrapassaria 5 tags